# How to rename a unit test suite in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created the test suite using:

1. File -> New -> Target.
2. Select "iOS Unit Testing Bundle"

The test suite is named CalculatorTest3, and I would like to rename it to CalculatorTest. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Just select for project name and then from the project targets select your newly created unit testing bundle and click it agin.
Now, 
1. Rename it as you want.[image]

2. Find the class created with the name same as unit testing bundle, rename it to new name.
3. Rename it also in info.plist [image]

Comment: after following these three steps my tempPrpject is running successfully (y)

Comment: Oh, I missed your third step. When I did that, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the name and after a second click again, you should be able to rename it directly.

Comment: I tried doing this earlier. But when I actually ran the tests, Xcode shut down unexpectedly, so I had to revert to a previous commit.